# how to remove values from an array but keep indexes intact

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array : `$myarray = array(153=>2 , 154=>0 , 155=>10 , 156=>15 , 157=>8)`

I did : `sort($myarray);` then , to remove the lowest ones, I did `array_shift` twice , but that reordered the indexes...but I need to keep the indexes unchanged.

Required output is `:$myarray = array(155=>10 , 156=>15 , 157=>8)`

The array is dynamic so indexes are unknown.

Comment: `unset($myarray[array_search(min($myarray), $myarray)]);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of: your error starts at using [`sort()`](https://www.php.net/sort) - it will reset keys. Use [`asort()`](https://www.php.net/asort) instead. Next, use [`array_slice()`](https://www.php.net/array_slice) with fourth parameter as `true` to preserve keys:

```
$myarray = array(153=>2 , 154=>0 , 155=>10 , 156=>15 , 157=>8);
asort($myarray);
$myarray = array_slice($myarray, 2, null, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the indexes you want to remove, you can simply do:

```
unset($myarray['first_index_here']);
[... unset more indexes ...]
```

see also the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.unset.php

If you want to remove the one with smallest value, as per @Leri suggestion, you can try:

```
unset($myarray[array_search(min($myarray), $myarray)]);
```

you can also make it into a function and then use it multiple times:

```
function unset_min(&$array) {
  unset($array[array_search(min($array), $array)]);
}

$myarray = array(153=>2 , 154=>0 , 155=>10 , 156=>15 , 157=>8);

// by hand
unset_min($myarray); // removed key 154
unset_min($myarray); // removed key 153

// or with loops
for($i = 0; $i < 2; ++$i) { // replace "2" with the actual number of entries to remove
  unset_min($myarray);
}
```

Comment: the indexes are unknown as the array is dynamic

Comment: then try the second option and let me know :)

Comment: sir , the seconds options works without any problem :) , thank you

Comment: I'm glad this was of help :) feel free to upvote my answer if it was useful tu you.

Comment: Sir, why did you use reference in the parameter of the unset_min() function ?

Comment: I did it so that the array you pass as parameter can be directly modified by the function, instead of having to return a modified copy.